# How to build/get a ConnectionProvider in Spring+Hibernate+C3P0 environment?

Tags: spring, hibernate, multi-tenant, c3p0

How to build/get a `ConnectionProvider` in a Spring(v.3.1.1) + Hibernate(v.4.1.1) + C3P0 environment?

**Background:**

In a Spring(v.3.1.1) + Hibernate(v.4.1.1) + C3P0 environment, I am trying to design a multi-tenant application. Hibernate has good [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) on newly introduced multitenancy features, but there are still some missing gaps. While following the example 16.3 in Hibernate docs, I couldn't figure out how to provide `ConnectionProvider` to `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`. Any hints/links/ideas would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the factory method `ConnectionProviderUtils.buildConnectionProvider(String);` to create an instance of a ConnectionProvider and then inject this into your `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`?

```
<bean id="multiTenantConnectionProvider" class="MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl">
  <property name="connectionProvider">
    <bean class="ConnectionProviderUtils" factory-method="buildConnectionProvider">
      <constructor-arg value="type"/> 
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Or something very close to that. Sorry i can't find the fully qualified class name of ConnectionProviderUtils, but both arguments to the class attributes must be fully qualified names.

Comment: And I cannot find ConnectionProviderUtils itself. Hibernate 4.1 documentation does show ConnectionProviderUtils in their example, but they don't tell where from to import it or how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer though!

Comment: Are you using a JNDI Connection Pooling? Try using org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider and injecting a datasource acquired via JNDI (see the 5th post on http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?13984-How-to-create-a-jndi-using-spring-datasource)